# How to send a push notification between 2 apps on ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have 2 apps that are meant for 2 separate roles - Buyer and Seller. Every time the buyer sends a message to seller I want to send a push notification and vise versa. A person can install both these apps on their phone .

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Possible but you have to follow some steps

First you have to Register Device token from both app and update in server db from login Ws or any other WS.

Then Create another WS for send pushnotification. for Exmple we have two App appA and appB. if we need to send PushNotification From appA to appB then call WS from appA in this WS do some code from server side.. get appB' s devoice Token and send them pushNotification. it's Easy. Let me know if any query will help's you.

Comment: By WS do you mean web service?

Comment: @NikhilGosavi yes WebService

Comment: Thanks. Have you implemented such a solution?

Comment: @NikhilGosavi yes it's possible. are you using PHP?

Comment: Cool. No I was exploring using Node JS

Comment: @NikhilGosavi okay nope. but you have to use backend service for this